# Parametric command line player

Tags: command-line, mp3, ogg-vorbis

I am looking for command line mp3 or ogg audio player with ability to play section of file, like: .... playfrom=145s playto=185s ....
The aim is to listen just the interesting part of audiorecording.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have compiled a complete list of commandline and other lightweight tools for linux. It also have list of music players too, check it out [Command Line Tools.](http://harbhag.wordpress.com/2010/07/02/best-lightweight-applications-for-linux/)

Here is my personal favorite [CMUS](http://cmus.sourceforge.net/) 
[image: CMUS]

Answer (score 1):

## [Sox](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=sox) [image: Install sox]

With the **Sox** audio processing tool we also get a player (`play`) that comes with a variety of options, including the possibility to trim playback to a given position in a file:

```
play filename trim mm:ss =mm:ss
```

Note that the `=` before the second time time says that we count from the beginning of the file. If omitted the second time gives the duration of the trimmed segment.